# Google spreadsheet complex formula

Tags: google-sheets

I am really new to the Google spreadsheet formulas. I have searched and searched and what I try I fail at in making this complex formula. I would appreciate any help given.

I am trying to get cells copied from sheet1 into a sheet3 based on answers/criteria in various cells in the row. If the project is completed then there are 6 Yes/No answers in each row. I need to copy the row information if it has "completed" in ColA along with copying specific cells if there is a Yes. 
For instance: Copy B and D:F plus if E=Yes copy E-J, if K=Yes copy K-L, if M=Yes copy M-Z, if AA=Yes copy AA-AD and so on. If there is a No to any of those just disregard do not copy.

I have tried this but it does not work: 
`=IF(Sheet1!M2="Yes", Sheet1!M2:W2, IF(Sheet1!X2="Yes", Sheet1!X2:AK2, IF(Sheet1!AL2="Yes", Sheet1!AL2:AS2, IF(Sheet1!AT2="Yes", Sheet1!AT2:AW, IF(Sheet1!AX2="Yes", Sheet1!AX2:AZ2, "")))))`

My Google spreadsheet is here, showing the content I want to move to Sheet3 :
[Testing spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ydCid8bQLw9a6onSt4cr8eFfh9FPc1G4JxV1uacxyQ0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Probably not the most helpful comment, but are you sure you wouldn't prefer to do it in googlescript/javascript instead? Spreadsheet formulas tend to become really hard to read/maintain/change when you add in too many statements (and ifs)

Comment: How would I do that in googlescript/javascript? I have never worked in that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is structured fine, the problem is that you cant refer to an array that way to pull in the row, however you could structure each portion of your if statement like this:

```
=if(Sheet1!A1="Yes",SPLIT(JOIN(";",Sheet1!1:1),";"))
```

Comment: Aurielle, thank you. Would you please explain the formula so I can understand how to put it all together a bit better.  I am still fresh on learning all this.

Comment: I tried this Aurielle but it did not work.  Did I not understand you correctly? `=if(Sheet1!M2="Yes",SPLIT(JOIN(";",Sheet1!M2:W2),";"), IF(Sheet1!X2="Yes",SPLIT(JOIN(";",Sheet1!X2:AK2),";"), IF(Sheet1!AL2="Yes",SPLIT(JOIN(";",Sheet1!AL2:AS2),";"), IF(Sheet1!AT2="Yes",SPLIT(JOIN(";",Sheet1!AT2:AW),";"), IF(Sheet1!AX2="Yes",SPLIT(JOIN(";",Sheet1!AX2:AZ2),";") )))))`

Comment: I think maybe I misunderstood something about the question? After taking a second look, before I suggest a different formula I have a question or two: One is when you say if it says yes in a column , you want to copy those, but it looks like there is no additional data if they say no, so in theory would you just want to copy the whole row if it says complete in A? I just want to understand what your ultimate goal is essentially , it will help me put a better formula together

Comment: The form I am using is very lengthy and asks several yes and no questions.  What I want to do is pull from each row is the data not the empty cells because they answered "NO" to a question leaving some blank cells since they answered "NO" they did not to answer those questions. I maybe making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: just a note - if you only pull int he data - skipping the blank cells - your columns will all be misaligned - how will you know which question pertains to which data point on the final sheet?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back with you but I have been handed more complex projects.  Yes you are correct Aurielle they will be out of whack but the information that comes after it will be compiled to be a description of the work performed.  I was going to try to append it all nicely together for the invoice. I just need to get this one done and off my plate.